# Can I improve Array filter in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance, search, filter, swiftui

I make some search bar in launching app.
I want to find some string that query contains regardless of lowercase and uppercase.
For Example when I search "par", "paris","parissss","safaParis" will appear.
I have a number of 5632 search item. so My code is this

```
List {
            HStack {
                TextField("Insert yout city", text: $searchTerm)
                Spacer()
                if self.searchTerm != "" {
                    Button(action:{
                        self.searchTerm=""
                    })
                    {
                        Image(systemName:"xmark.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        
                    } .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    
                }
            }   .padding(10)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    // .strokeBorder(Color("a1"), lineWidth: 3))
                    .strokeBorder( LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("a3"),Color("a2")]),
                                                  startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), lineWidth: 3))
            
            
            if self.searchTerm.count > 1 {
                ForEach((self.cities.filter { (value:String)->Bool in
                    return value.lowercased().contains(self.searchTerm.lowercased())
                }),
                        id: \.self)  { city in
                            CityRow(city: city,selectedCity: self.$selectedCity,isshow:self.$showSearchView, poiListData: self.$POIinCity)
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }.padding(.top)
    .background(Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

But I'm dissapointed at this performance. About 2~3 seconds, thread is stopped.
when I delete lowercase sentence in that code, it work well.
How can I acheive good performance about Array filter??

Comment: `value.localizedStandardContains(self.searchTerm)`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416328-localizedstandardcontains **Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the string contains a given string by performing a case and diacritic insensitive, locale-aware search.**

Comment: Thanks for your advise. but it's performance is the same...

Comment: one thing you could do is to pre-create a lowercase'd array of `self.cities` instead of doing this for each comparison (not sure how much that would help though). The right approach though is to do the filtering off the main thread so as to not lock up the UI

Comment: Are you doing this in a release build or debug build? There's little point in worrying about performance in an unoptimized debug build with tons of safety checks. Do a release build and let us know what the performance is like.

Comment: Any heavy activity in main queue (filtering is such) will block UI, so move it into background queue and update main queue with results (complete or partial in sequence, interruptible or not, etc.), but it definitely should not be done synchronously on view refresh.

Comment: Thank you all your comments.